# How to make 'keymap disabled by me' still take effect after Blender restarts in Python?

Tags: python, add-on

[How to modify a key and register another key at the same time in an addon? on Blender Artists Forum](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-modify-a-key-and-register-another-key-at-the-same-time-in-an-addon/1336649)

I disabled the default key positions in Python based on the method of this website. I was able to successfully disable and restore the default key positions when the plugin was turned on and off, but it did not automatically start after the blender was restarted. I had to restart and close the plugin to take effect

On this [website](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-modify-a-key-and-register-another-key-at-the-same-time-in-an-addon/1336649), the user `iceythe` seems to be able to solve this problem, but his method is

```
wm = bpy.context.window_manager
if "3D View Generic" not in wm.keyconfigs.active.keymaps:
    return bpy.app.timers.register(register, first_interval=0.1)
```

Such individual-specific conditions

But the shortcut key I disabled contains many spaces, which are a list/array. How can I write it more efficiently to achieve "restart blender and automatically disable default key mapping when my plugin is turned on"?

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "TTTl",
    "description": "TTT.",
    "author": "TTTTTT",
    "version": (1, 3, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "View3D > TOOLS > TTTT",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "System"
}


import bpy


disabled_kmis = []


def get_active_kmi(space: str, **kwargs) -> bpy.types.KeyMapItem:
    kc = bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.active
    km = kc.keymaps.get(space)
    if km:
        for kmi in km.keymap_items:
            for key, val in kwargs.items():
                if getattr(kmi, key) != val and val is not None:
                    break
            else:
                return kmi
            

def disable_kmi(space, idname, type, shift=False, ctrl=False, alt=False, properties=None):
    kmi = get_active_kmi(space,
    idname=idname,
    type=type,
    shift=shift,
    ctrl=ctrl,
    alt=alt,
    properties=properties)

    if kmi is not None:
        kmi.active = False
        disabled_kmis.append(kmi)


def disable_default_keymaps():
    global disabled_kmis
    disable_kmi("3D View", "wm.search_menu", 'Tab')
    disable_kmi("3D View", "wm.call_menu_pie", 'V')
    disable_kmi("3D View", "view3d.view_all", 'A')
    disable_kmi("3D View", "view3d.view_all", 'A',shift=True)
    disable_kmi("3D View", "view3d.zoom_border", 'Z')
    disable_kmi("Mesh", "wm.call_menu", 'RIGHTMOUSE')
    disable_kmi("Mesh", "wm.tool_set_by_id", 'C',alt=True)
    disable_kmi("Mesh", "wm.tool_set_by_id", 'C')
    disable_kmi("Mesh", "wm.context_toggle", 'B')
    disable_kmi("Mesh", "wm.tool_set_by_id", 'D')
    disable_kmi("Mesh", "wm.tool_set_by_id", 'Q')
    disable_kmi("Mesh", "mesh.select_all", 'A',alt=True)
    disable_kmi("Object Mode", "wm.call_menu", 'RIGHTMOUSE')
    disable_kmi("Object Mode", "object.select_all", 'A', ctrl=True)
    disable_kmi("Object Mode", "wm.tool_set_by_id", 'C')
    disable_kmi("Object Mode", "wm.tool_set_by_id", 'D')
    disable_kmi("Object Mode", "wm.tool_set_by_id", 'Q')
    disable_kmi("Sculpt", "paint.mask_box_gesture", 'B')
    disable_kmi("Sculpt", "wm.tool_set_by_id", 'Q')
    disable_kmi("Sculpt", "brush.stencil_control", 'RIGHTMOUSE')
    disable_kmi("Sculpt", "brush.stencil_control", 'RIGHTMOUSE',shift=True)
    disable_kmi("Sculpt", "brush.stencil_control", 'RIGHTMOUSE',ctrl=True)
    disable_kmi("Sculpt", "wm.call_panel", 'RIGHTMOUSE')
    disable_kmi("Sculpt", "paint.brush_select", 'D')
    disable_kmi("Sculpt", "paint.brush_select", 'B')
    disable_kmi("Sculpt", "sculpt.dyntopo_detail_size_edit", 'D',shift=True)
    disable_kmi("Image", "image.change_frame", 'LEFTMOUSE')
    disable_kmi("Image", "image.sample", 'LEFTMOUSE')
    disable_kmi("Image", "wm.tool_set_by_id", 'LEFTMOUSE')
    disable_kmi("Image", "wm.tool_set_by_id", 'C')
    disable_kmi("UV Editor", "wm.call_menu", 'RIGHTMOUSE')
    disable_kmi("UV Editor", "wm.tool_set_by_id", 'C')
    disable_kmi("Frames", "screen.animation_play", 'SPACE')
    

def enable__default_keymaps():
    for kmi in disabled_kmis:
        kmi.active = True


def register():
    disable_default_keymaps()


def unregister():
    enable__default_keymaps()
    disabled_kmis.clear()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```